# QuantLib how to use in goland?

Tags: go, quantlib, quantlib-swig

to calculate option price which use QuantLib,but QuantLib do not supported in goland.

"QuantLib is written in C++ with a clean object model, and is then exported to different languages such as C#, Java, Python, R, and Ruby."

https://www.quantlib.org/

Answer (score 0):

QuantLib is exported to different languages using SWIG, which generates the necessary wrapper code.  Unfortunately, SWIG for Go does not support the `shared_ptr` class, which is used everywhere in the interfaces.  Therefore, QuantLib cannot support Go until this changes.

There is an issue open for SWIG on GitHub to add this feature (see https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/2030) but no working contributions so far.

Comment: so sad...... no any crazy man make it use?